# Why does my file thats linked to a Jar work in VS code but not in terminal

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal, jar, dbconnection

I'm having trouble trying to understand why my program will only work in VS code. When  I select inside VS code to run it will populate my gui table. However if I try to run the file inside the terminal while inside the code

```
java DbConnection.java
```

This is whats inside my .vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "/Users/mattgranado/Desktop/SQLiteJDBC/**/*.jar"
    ]
}
```

the error below will occur.

[image]

Comment: what do you have in `.vscode/settings.json`? I think is working on vscode because is adding your external libs on classpath. but when you run on terminal is getting only current project. you need add your external lib in your current process ( eg. adding external jars on class path , using a build tool  ( maven or gradle ) to generate fatJat with all jar inside ).

Comment: try run on terminal like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/219801/7505687 but I suggest you using a tool for manage dependencies and build like maven or gradle and have happy life :)

Comment: .vscode/settings.json
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "/Users/mattgranado/Desktop/SQLiteJDBC/**/*.jar"
    ]
}

@DilermandoLima

Comment: Please refer to the link @DilermandoLima shared that compile .java file with .jar then see if the question goes away.